# C# - Windows Phone - MaxWidth & MaxHeight property being ignored

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, canvas, windows-phone-8, css

I have some Canvases in a ListBox. Inside these Canvases I have some TextBlocks which have their text bound to them. However when I try to use a MaxWidth/Height property on the text block (or the standard Height/Width), the properties are ignored! So I end up with the text overspilling the Canvas in cases.

I would much appreciate any help on the matter, and I hope I'm not just being a blind idiot!

Oh, and here's the code (the TextBlock I'm talking about is the first one):

```
<ListBox Margin="0,-9,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="listBoxNotes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="548">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Canvas Height="175" Width="360" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Name="canvasNote" Tap="canvasNote_Tap">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="26" Foreground="White" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="5" x:Name="Title" Width="100" MaxWidth="100"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="352" FontSize="24" Foreground="White" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="35" />
                </Canvas>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you show some code.

Comment: Added some code, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this is Canvas does not limit the size of their children, and especially the`TextBlock` control will grow as much as it needs.

Many ways to solve your problem :

- Do not use `TextBlock` but a `TextBox`
- Do not use `Canvas` but another container such as `Border`, `Grid`, `StackPanel`...
- Try to clip the `TextBlock` content

`<TextBlock.Clip>
      <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 50, 30"/>
 </TextBlock.Clip>`

Comment: Thanks alot! I'll use grids from now on then!

Comment: Actually I have one more problem, how can I access one of the child TextBlocks of the Grid?